# YII 1.1 Nested Module not Working

Tags: php, yii, routes

I have faced the problem for conflict the routes in YII 1.1.
Parent and child module have the same name. but actual URL is Different.

**File Structure**

```
+ modules
 + module1
  + controller
   ...
   + modules
    + module2
      + controller
       ...
 + module2
  + controller
  ...
```

**Config/Main.php**

```
'module1'=>array('modules'=>array('module2')),
'module2',
```

**route**

```
1) http://XXX:8000/index.php/module1/default/index
2) http://XXX:8000/index.php/module2/default/index
3) http://XXX:8000/index.php/module1/module2/default/index
```

3rd URL roted to URL 2.

When i called module1 or module2 controllers it's work fine.
but i called module1/module2 controller it's routes to base module 'module2'.

my URLManager

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm having the same issue. any suggestions?

Comment: Having the same problem here. Find out that until version 1.1.15 it works fine. In 1.1.16 it breaks